# AjaxLink stopped working in Wicket 1.5

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

Java:

```
item.add(new AjaxLink("edit"){
   @Override
   public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
      setResponsePage(new UnitPage(unit));
   }
 });
```

HTML:

```
<td><button wicket:id="edit">Edit</button></td>
```

This worked fine in 1.4 - clicking the button would take me to the new page with a "unit" object passed as parameter.

In 1.5 this is no longer working - it doesn't look like the onClick is firing.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the response page will cause a full page refresh so you could use a standard Link instead of AjaxLink.

That said, the wicket examples have such an example which seems to work.